# PHP - preg_match() result in 0 matching values

Tags: php, preg-match

I was trying to do web scraping for my personal webpage, using the bio and pics from a website profile (http://about.me/fernandocaldas) so whenever I change that profile the content in my web bio will also do.
The desired values are between

```
    <script type="text/json" class="json user" data-scope="view_profile" data-lowercase_user_name="fernandocaldas">
```

and

```
    </script>
```

Here is my code:

```
$thtml = file_get_contents('http://about.me/fernandocaldas');
$matchval = '/\<script type=\"text\/json\" class=\"json.*?>(.*?)\<\/script\>/i';
preg_match($matchval, $thtml, $match);
var_dump($match);
if($match){
    echo "match!\n";
     foreach($match[1] as $val)
    {
        echo $val."<br>";
    }
}
```

But the result is always `array(0) {}` for the `var_dump`.

Comment: use DOMDocument and DOMXPath

Comment: I don't really understand why you would expect this to work. The regular expression you are using doesn't even look vaguely like it would match the HTML you have given. In any case I second @CasimiretHippolyte's suggestion of parsing the HTML properly.

Comment: Revisiting this, I was not even near with the regex. Thanks for your time and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are never a good idea for HTML: today regex seems to work, but tomorrow they will fail!<sup>1</sup>

Frequently programmers think: “why I have to init a parser, load the HTML, performs a lot of queries if I can do it with only one line of regex code?”. The answer is “why choose the road that leads you in the wrong direction, although shorter?”.

In your case by using a Parser **you can also shorten your code**.

First, load your HTML page, init a new `DOMDocument` object, load HTML string into it and init a `DOMXPath` object (`DOMXPath` permits to perform complex HTML queries):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(1);
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
```

Search for the element(s) with tag `<script>` and class “json user”:

```
$found = $xpath->query( '//script[@class="json user"]' );
if( !$found->length ) die( 'Error retrieving JSON' );
```

Put the node value of first (and unique, in your page) node in a variable (I also `trim` it, but it is unnecessary) and decode it with `json_decode()`:

```
$json = trim( $found->item(0)->nodeValue );
$user = json_decode( $json );
```

Now, in `$user` object, you have all the data you need. In `$user->first_name` you have your first name, in `$user->bio` you have your biography. By a `print_r( $user )` you can display the complete `$user` structure to see how to access to each element.

---

- Read more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- Read more about [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)
- Read **[why you can't parse [X]HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3294262)**

---

<sup>1</sup> If the HTML structure change, also a parser will fail.

Comment: *"today regex seems to work, but tomorrow they will fail!"*: Note that it can be also the case with DOMDocument.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, totally right. And with any other parser also.

Comment: You can't imagine to write code by copy-and-paste. Also if your code doesn't work you have to check for your own errors before throw in the towel. I test my code before answering, and identical above code (on http://about.me/fernandocaldas, as per your question) yesterday it worked. Today... it works again: see [this demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/s5mn-30kd)

Comment: Forgive me for the vague comment, It was my big mistake to use readfile() instead of file_get_contents() for retrieving the data. Many thanks for helping me.